# How to save the output as csv file in python

Tags: python, rabbitmq, python-2.x, rabbitmqctl

I use this Python snippet to obtain the rabbitmq queue size output, which is already in csv format, however I would need to know how to save this data to a file.

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues --formatter csv", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
print stdout_value
```

Output i get from this snippet

```
"name","messages"
"search_publish_queue","1"
.
.
```

I tried to write the output to a csv file using `with open`, it writes however it add , next to every character.

```
import subprocess
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'w', ) as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues --formatter csv", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
    writer.writerow(stdout_value)
```

It writes to file as below

```
",n,a,m,e,",",m,e,s,s,a,g,e,s,"
",s,e,a,r,c,h,_,p,u,b,l,i,s,h,_,q,u,e,u,e,",,,",1,"
```

Whats the write way to do this? if not using

Comment: It's already a CSV, you can just write it directly to the file, you don't need to use `csv()`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried, but I am not sure if that's the right way of handling the file. Below snippet works for me, i want to understand if that's the correct way of handling


`import subprocess

file = open("myfile.csv","w")
proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues --formatter csv", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]
file.write(stdout_value)`

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You used `--format csv` to tell `rabbitmqctl` to output in CSV format. You can also have `subprocess.run()` write directly to the file, with `stdout=f`

Comment: @Barmar Please educate me on that, how do i write to file using `subprocess.run()`

Comment: `subprocess.run("command", shell=True, stdout=f)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is that writer.writerow expects an iterable of fields to write as a single row. In your case, stdout_value is actually a byte string, so when you pass it to writer.writerow, the function tries to iterate over each byte, which leads to the incorrect output you're seeing.

There are a few ways to solve this problem. One approach is to decode stdout_value to a regular string and write it directly to the file. Since your data is already in CSV format, you don't need to use the csv module for this particular case:

```
import subprocess

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues --formatter csv", shell=True, stdout=f)
    proc.communicate()
```

In this example, I used 'wb' as the file mode to write bytes directly to the file. I also passed f directly as the stdout parameter to Popen, which makes it write the output directly to the file.

Alternatively, if you still want to read the data into a variable first, you can do the following:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen("/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl list_queues --formatter csv", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout_value = proc.communicate()[0]

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(stdout_value)
```

In this case, I've used the 'wb' mode to write the bytes as they are. Note that the stdout_value is a bytes object, so we can write it directly to a file opened in binary mode ('wb'). I hope this helps!